The class FPDF of library fpdf has no attribute 'table'
I'm trying to create a table in Python using the FPDF library. The following code gives me an error: 'FPDF' object has no attribute 'table'. I don't know how to solve it. I will be grateful for your help.
Code:
import fpdf
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()

TABLE_Data = (('Etap' , 'Czas rozpoczecia' , 'Czas trwania'),
                  ('Wychladzanie pieca' , 'IDLE_start' , ''),
                  ('NIF temp = 1200C' , 'IDLE_step1' , 'IDLE_time_step1'),
                  ('Przycisk DROP' , 'IDLE_step2' , 'IDLE_time_step2'),
                  ('DROP' , 'IDLE_step3' , 'IDLE_time_step3'),
                  ('Preciki - START' , 'IDLE_step4' , 'IDLE_time_step4'),
                  ('Preciki - STOP' , 'IDLE_step5' , 'IDLE_time_step5'),
                  ('V = 15 m/min' , 'IDLE_step6' , 'IDLE_time_step6'),
                  ('V = 50 m/min' , 'IDLE_step7' , 'IDLE_time_step7'),
                  ('Srednica w tolerancji' , 'IDLE_step8' , 'IDLE_time_good'),
                  ('Predkosc robocza' , 'IDLE_end' , 'IDLE_time_end')
                  )
pdf.add_page()

pdf.set_font('Helvetica', 'b', 18) 

with pdf.table() as table:
    for data_row in TABLE_Data:
        row = table.row()
        for datum in data_row:
            row.cell(datum)


pdf.output('table.pdf')

I was looking for answers on the forums. The only information was regarding: pdf.add_page() and pdf.set_font(), but both options are declared in my example.

According to fpdf , the table method is not exist
if your target is to create the table like this

you have to manually draw table structure
Eg:
Create class containing all the method you need manually and use them. pass the FPDF to the class

For the above pdf image python code

Thank you very much for your answer. I admit that I solved the problem a bit in a roundabout way. I used the module: dataframe_image and uploaded the table as a picture.

You are using old version of pyfpdf
I think that in your system you have installed the old version of pyfpdf. The documentation of this old version is here. As you can see in the documentation the class FPDF of the old library pyfpdf doesn't have any attribute table, so the error:
AttributeError: 'FPDF' object has no attribute 'table'

is obvious.
You can remove this old version and install the new by the command:
pip install fpdf2

How to insert data into a table by old version of pyfpdf
But if you want to use the old version of pyfpdf I'll show you a working python code which is able to write data of your tuple TABLE_Data in a table inside a file  PDF:
import fpdf
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()

TABLE_Data = (('Etap' , 'Czas rozpoczecia' , 'Czas trwania'),
                  ('Wychladzanie pieca' , 'IDLE_start' , ''),
                  ('NIF temp = 1200C' , 'IDLE_step1' , 'IDLE_time_step1'),
                  ('Przycisk DROP' , 'IDLE_step2' , 'IDLE_time_step2'),
                  ('DROP' , 'IDLE_step3' , 'IDLE_time_step3'),
                  ('Preciki - START' , 'IDLE_step4' , 'IDLE_time_step4'),
                  ('Preciki - STOP' , 'IDLE_step5' , 'IDLE_time_step5'),
                  ('V = 15 m/min' , 'IDLE_step6' , 'IDLE_time_step6'),
                  ('V = 50 m/min' , 'IDLE_step7' , 'IDLE_time_step7'),
                  ('Srednica w tolerancji' , 'IDLE_step8' , 'IDLE_time_good'),
                  ('Predkosc robocza' , 'IDLE_end' , 'IDLE_time_end')
                  )
pdf.add_page()

pdf.ln(10)
pdf.set_font('Helvetica', 'b', 15)

for data_row in TABLE_Data:
    for data in data_row:
        pdf.cell(w=60, h=10, txt=str(data), border=1)
    pdf.ln()

pdf.output('table.pdf')

Some notes:

I have reduced the size of your Helvetica char font to 15 because 18 is too big; it remains in bold (this because the second arguments of set_font() is equal to b)
the number that are present as arguments in the instructions pdf.ln(10) and pdf.cell(w=60, h=10, txt=str(data), border=1) are in millimeter because millimeter is the default unit used.

The table inserted, by the python code, inside the file table.pdf is showed below:

